# Cannot publish a MongoDB collection from the server to client Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections, publish, publish-subscribe

I want to publish a sever side collection to the client side.

**In Server Side**

```
MedicalCenters = new Mongo.Collection('medicalCenters');

Meteor.publish('medicalCenters',function () {
    return MedicalCenters.find({});
});
```

I want this collection only to be accessed by a particular template. Thefore,

**In Client Side**

```
Template.doctor.onCreated(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('medicalCenters');
});
```

Now I can pass the data from client side template and even write to the serve side collection. But it seems to be subscription did not work and therefore, I cannot display collection data in the template. 
*(The collection is not displayed in the meteortoys Mongol)*

How do I fix this?

Comment: What file structure are you using? Are you using the ```/imports``` directory?

Also, have you got a helper to display the info from the subscription in the template?

Comment: I do not use /imports, I use a custom file structure. How do I refer the collection in helpers? (in what name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have not placed your collection definition code in a common location that is executed by both the client and server.  I'm making this assumption because you said that the collection itself was not visible in `mongol`.

Remember that in order for publish/subscribe to work, collections must exist on both the client side (using minimongo) and the server side (using mongodb).

Refer to the [Meteor Application Structure](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) guide for the details, but essentially you should put your collection definition code in a file that is not within a special directory (e.g. the `server/` or `client/` folder).  Doing so ensures that the code is executed by both the client and server (per the [meteor api docs](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#files-outside)).

> All JavaScript files outside special directories are loaded on both the client and the server.

In the older meteor days (before we had the `imports/` folder) people often placed their collection definition code inside a `lib/` folder within the meteor project root.  Now it's common for it to be within the `import/api/` directory as described [here](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure).

Comment: Thank you very much. I put the collection definition on the root folder and now it is displayed in the Mongol.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a helper to send the data to the template:

```
Template.doctor.helpers({
  medicalcenters() {
    return MedicalCenters.find();
  }
});
```

Then in your template you can loop through the medical centers

```
<template name="doctor">
    {{#each medicalcenters}}
        {{name}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```